# Insert double quotation about double quotation mark in string java?

Tags: java, quotes

Hello to the community what I need is to have this code in a string:

```
String nameTablePOJO = "   @Table(name = "\"SGEstado\"", schema = "\"public\""    "
```

Please someone can guide me in quote with this expression. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want something like

```
String nameTablePOJO = "   @Table(name = \"\\\"SGEstado\\\"\", "
    + "schema = \"\\\"public\\\"\")";
System.out.println(nameTablePOJO);
```

Output is

```
@Table(name = "\"SGEstado\"", schema = "\"public\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Java, you can escape quotes with \ :**

In your case,

```
  String nameTablePOJO = " @Table(name = \"\\\"SGEstado\\\"\", "
        + "schema = \"\\\"public\\\"\")";
```